# macro vs procedure in assembly

Tags: assembly, macros

I'm learning now how to use macros in assembly language.
I know that macros are faster than procedures because there's no costly jumps, only copying the lines.

But I don't understand why macros take more memory than procedure.

Answer (score 4):

Macros only take more memory under certain conditions:

- The macro is used more than once
- The expanded macro takes more memory than the code to call the procedure

Once the above is true, the (big enough) macro body is duplicated (more than once), so it takes more memory than the procedure, whose body is only generated once.

Comment: In what circumstances does a macro take less memory than the code to call the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

With a macro the same code is duplicated in multiple places in memory, instead of reusing the same procedure.

Answer (score 1):

They take more memory exactly because they copy the lines - so the code is copied each time you use a macro, increasing the executable size.

Answer (score 0):

macro take more memory because it copy the line when we call it but it's coding done exactly one time as compare to proceure , procedure coding generated exactly one time that's why macro is faster than procedure